# Powershell Detecting When Device Is Added Or Removed

Tags: node.js, powershell, nwjs

I have a Node JS NW.js/Angular app that continuously runs a PowerShell script every 5 seconds to get the currently connected removable storage devices (USB thumb drives, SD cards) that I then show to the user in the UI.  My question is: Is there anything I can do on the PowerShell script itself to notify me of changes rather then running it in a continuous loop?  It seems fine now and working smoothly, just wondering if there's a "better" way.  I'm using the [node-powershell library from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell) to call the command from a simple JavaScript setInterval() method.

```
ConvertTo-Json @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter ("DriveType=2 AND FileSystem IS NOT NULL"))
```

Comment: it seems that you can register an action to happen when an event occurs. the `Register-WmiEvent` and `Register-CimIndicationEvent` both seem to be able to do what your code is doing. i do not know if you need to leave a powershell session running for it to work, tho. [*blush*] i've only read about the two cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook a Scheduled Task to a Windows hardware change event. Hardware change event ID detected > Task is triggered > Task calls your script...

> Connection Event IDs When a USB removable storage device is connected
>   to a Windows 7 system, a number of event records should be generated
>   in the Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational event
>   log. The records include those with Event ID 2003, 2004, 2005, 2010,
>   2100, 2105, and more. ...
>
> Disconnection Event IDs When a USB thumb drive is disconnected from a
>   Windows 7 system, a few event records should be generated in the same
>   event log as the connection events. Records with Event ID 2100, 2102,
>   and potentially more may be generated when a USB device is
>   disconnected. ...